# How to use StringArray type Parameter in Pentaho CDA?

Tags: arrays, parameters, pentaho, cda

Does anyone knows how to use parameter of type StringArray in Pentaho CDA?

```
<DataAccess id="Testing_StringArrayParam" 
    connection="2" 
    type="sql" 
    access="public">
    <Name>Testing String Array Parameter</Name>
    <Query>
        select distinct all_functional_areas.functional_area_name
    from tbl_cand_organization_mst all_companies,
        tbl_cand_functional_area_mst all_functional_areas 
    where all_companies.organization_name=${ClientName})
    </Query>
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter name="ClientName" type="StringArray"/>
    </Parameters>
    <Columns>
        <Column idx="0"><Name>Functional_Area</Name></Column>
    </Columns>
    <Output indexes="0"/>
</DataAccess>
```

I would like to know how to give array of values for `ClientName` parameter?

If anyone knows it, then please let me know. I am not able to find answer about this thing anywhere. Samples given with CDA do not use `StringArray` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CDA will replace

```
${ClientName}
```

with

```
"Client1", "Client2", "Client3"
```

.

So you just need the query to read

```
select distinct all_functional_areas.functional_area_name
    from tbl_cand_organization_mst all_companies,
    tbl_cand_functional_area_mst all_functional_areas 
where all_companies.organization_name in (${ClientName})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I had to go through test cases present here http://code.google.com/p/pentaho-cda/source/browse/trunk/test/pt/webdetails/cda/tests/?r=381 , to know how to use StringArray type parameter.

Comment: We really need to remove that repository -- CDA has been moved to github (https://github.com/webdetails/cda)

Comment: well, you need to create documentation also. CDA is really really great but lacks documentation. I would love to help you guyz.